# How to disable date based on the current time in jQuery UI Datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a  multi-step form for customer order system. In one step I have implemented a jQuery UI Datepicker for customers to select their Collection and Delivery Dates.

It works great so far, but one additional feature I want to add with this datepicker; i.e. if the Current Time is less than or equal to 10am (before 10am) user can select the current date as delivery date, but if ordering after 10am current date should be disabled, and also if the user is ordering on friday after 10am, then block the following Saturday and Sunday in delivery date.

Any help will be great, thanks in advance.

Here is my idea about doing this -

```
var dt = new Date();
    var hour = dt.getHours();
    if(parseInt(hour, 10) > 10) {
       //want to set minDate=+1 here
    } else {
        //want to set minDate=0 here
    }
```

Comment: @isherwood - please check my updated Question, I have no idea about where this should go, onSelect method will not work i think. want to work this on init the datepicker. right??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var minDate = null;

...

if(parseInt(hour, 10) > 10) {
    minDate = 1;
}

$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
    minDate: minDate;
});
```

- http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

Comment: thanks for your help, can you help me on second part of the question, ie - if the user is ordering on friday after 10am, then block the following saturday and sunday in delivery date calendar??

Comment: That probably warrants a new question.